# POSIX SH build loop variable with elements containing spaces

Tags: bash, sh

Here's the code I need:

```
#!/bin/sh

x1="a1 a2"
x2="b1 b2"

list=SOMETHING

for x in "$list"
do
    echo $x
done
```

And the output I want:

```
a1 a2
b1 b2
```

The question is: what should `SOMETHING` be? I want `$list` to behave just as `$@` does.

Notes: I can't use `$IFS` and I can't `eval` the entire loop.

Comment: related: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/102891/posix-compliant-way-to-work-with-a-list-of-filenames-possibly-with-whitespace/102904 | bash: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9084257/bash-array-with-spaces-in-elements

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is probably as close as you can get:

```
#!/bin/sh
x1="a1 a2"
x2="b1 b2"

set -- "$x1" "$x2"

for x in "$@"
do
    # echo $x
    echo "[${x}]"    # proves that the lines are being printed separately
done
```

Output:

```
[a1 a2]
[b1 b2]
```

In Bash you can use an array:

```
#!/bin/bash
x1="a1 a2"
x2="b1 b2"

list=("$x1" "$x2")

for x in "${list[@]}"
do
    # echo $x
    echo "[${x}]"    # proves that the lines are being printed separately
done
```

Same output.

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible in standard POSIX shell.

Comment: As $@ does what I want I was hoping it would be possible