# Bash array with spaces in elements

Tags: arrays, bash, unix, scripting

I'm trying to construct an array in bash of the filenames from my camera:

```
FILES=(2011-09-04 21.43.02.jpg
2011-09-05 10.23.14.jpg
2011-09-09 12.31.16.jpg
2011-09-11 08.43.12.jpg)
```

As you can see, there is a space in the middle of each filename.

I've tried wrapping each name in quotes, and escaping the space with a backslash, neither of which works.

When I try to access the array elements, it continues to treat the space as the elementdelimiter.

How can I properly capture the filenames with a space inside the name?

Comment: Have you tried adding the files the old-fashioned way? Like `FILES[0] = ...`? (Edit: I just did; doesn't work. Interesting).

Comment: POSIX: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2936922/posix-sh-build-loop-variable-with-elements-containing-spaces

Comment: All of the answers here break down for me using Cygwin. It does weird things if there are spaces in file names, period. I work around it by creating an "array" in a text file listing of all elements I want to work with, and iterating over lines in the file:

Formatting is mucking with intended backticks here surrounding the command in parenthesis:

IFS=""; array=(`find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -iname \*.$1 -printf '%f\n'`); for element in ${array[@]}; do echo $element; done

Answer (score 161, accepted):

I think the issue might be partly with how you're accessing the elements. If I do a simple `for elem in $FILES`, I experience the same issue as you. However, if I access the array through its indices, like so, it works if I add the elements either numerically or with escapes:

```
for ((i = 0; i < ${#FILES[@]}; i++))
do
    echo "${FILES[$i]}"
done
```

Any of these declarations of `$FILES` should work:

```
FILES=(2011-09-04\ 21.43.02.jpg
2011-09-05\ 10.23.14.jpg
2011-09-09\ 12.31.16.jpg
2011-09-11\ 08.43.12.jpg)
```

or

```
FILES=("2011-09-04 21.43.02.jpg"
"2011-09-05 10.23.14.jpg"
"2011-09-09 12.31.16.jpg"
"2011-09-11 08.43.12.jpg")
```

or

```
FILES[0]="2011-09-04 21.43.02.jpg"
FILES[1]="2011-09-05 10.23.14.jpg"
FILES[2]="2011-09-09 12.31.16.jpg"
FILES[3]="2011-09-11 08.43.12.jpg"
```

Comment: Note that you should use double-quotes when you use the array elements (e.g. `echo "${FILES[$i]}"`).  It doesn't matter for `echo`, but it will for anything that uses it as a filename.

Comment: It's not necessary to loop over the indexes when you can loop over the elements with `for f in "${FILES[@]}"`.

Comment: @MarkEdgar i experiencing problems with **for f in ${FILES[@]}** when the array members have spaces. It seems that the whole array is reinterpreted again, with the spaces spitting your existing members into two or more elements. It seems the " " are very important

Comment: Whats does the sharp (`#`) symbol do in `for ((i = 0; i < ${#FILES[@]}; i++))` statement?

Comment: I answered this six years ago but I believe it's to get the *count* of the number of elements in the array FILES.

Comment: `${FILES[@]}` returns the contents of the array.
`${#FILES[@]}` returns the count of elements in the array. (self-contained answer).

Comment: bash array index is 1-based

Answer (score 127):

There must be something wrong with the way you access the array's items. Here's how it's done:

```
for elem in "${files[@]}"
...
```

From the [bash manpage](http://linux.die.net/man/1/bash):

> Any element of an array may be referenced using ${name[subscript]}. ... If subscript is @ or *, the word expands to all members of name. These subscripts differ only when the word appears within double quotes. **If the word is double-quoted,** ${name[*]} expands to a single word with the value of each array member separated by the first character of the IFS special variable, and **${name[@]} expands each element of name to a separate word**.

Of course, you should also use double quotes when accessing a single member

```
cp "${files[0]}" /tmp
```

Comment: Cleanest, most elegant solution in this bunch, though should re-iterate that each element defined in the array should be quoted.

Comment: While Dan Fego's answer is effective, this is the more idiomatic way to handle spaces in the elements.

Comment: Coming from other programming languages, the terminology from that excerpt is really hard to understand. Plus the syntax is baffling. I'd be extremely grateful if you could go into it a bit more? Particularly `expands to a single word with the value of each array member separated by the first character of the IFS special variable`

Comment: Yes, agree the double quotes are solving it and this is better than other solutions.  To further explain - most others are just lacking the double quotes.  You got the correct: `for elem in "${files[@]}"`, while they have `for elem in ${files[@]}` - so the spaces confuse the expansion and for tries running on the individual words.

Comment: This does not work for me in macOS 10.14.4, which uses "GNU bash, version 3.2.57(1)-release (x86_64-apple-darwin18)". Maybe a bug in the older version of bash?

Comment: IFS=$'\n'
IMPORTANT - IFS= Internal Field Separator, changes break point for arrays!!! no break on spaces

Answer (score 60):

You need to use IFS to stop space as element delimiter.

```
FILES=("2011-09-04 21.43.02.jpg"
       "2011-09-05 10.23.14.jpg"
       "2011-09-09 12.31.16.jpg"
       "2011-09-11 08.43.12.jpg")
IFS=""
for jpg in ${FILES[*]}
do
    echo "${jpg}"
done
```

If you want to separate on basis of . then just do IFS="."
Hope it helps you:)

Comment: I had to move the IFS="" to before the array assignment but this is the correct answer.

Comment: I am using several arrays to parse info and I shall have the effect of IFS="" working in only one of them. Once I use IFS="" all other arrays stop parsing accordingly. Any hints about this?

Comment: Paulo, see another answer here which may be better for your case: https://stackoverflow.com/a/9089186/1041319.  Have not tried IFS="", and seems it does solve it elegantly - but your example shows why one may encounter issues in some cases.  It may be possible to set the IFS="" on a single line, but it may still be more confusing than the other solution.

Comment: It also worked for me on bash. Thanks @Khushneet I was searching it for half an hour...

Comment: Great, only answer on this page that worked. But I also had to move the `IFS=""` **before the array construction**.

Comment: What is this Satanic black magic?! (Apparently it is [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/184867))

Comment: This was the only solution that worked for me. However, as others have mentioned, IFS needs to be set *before* array assignment.

Answer (score 17):

I agree with others that it's likely how you're accessing the elements that is the problem. Quoting the file names in the array assignment is correct:

```
FILES=(
  "2011-09-04 21.43.02.jpg"
  "2011-09-05 10.23.14.jpg"
  "2011-09-09 12.31.16.jpg"
  "2011-09-11 08.43.12.jpg"
)

for f in "${FILES[@]}"
do
  echo "$f"
done
```

Using double quotes around any array of the form `"${FILES[@]}"` splits the array into one word per array element. It doesn't do any word-splitting beyond that.

Using `"${FILES[*]}"` also has a special meaning, but it *joins* the array elements with the first character of $IFS, resulting in *one* word, which is probably not what you want.

Using a bare `${array[@]}` or `${array[*]}` subjects the result of that expansion to further word-splitting, so you'll end up with words split on spaces (and anything else in `$IFS`) instead of one word per array element.

Using a C-style for loop is also fine and avoids worrying about word-splitting if you're not clear on it:

```
for (( i = 0; i < ${#FILES[@]}; i++ ))
do
  echo "${FILES[$i]}"
done
```

Answer (score 13):

This was already answered [above](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9089186/2150289), but that answer was a bit terse and the man page excerpt is a bit cryptic. I wanted to provide a fully worked example to demonstrate how this works in practice.

If not quoted, an array just expands to strings separated by spaces, so that

```
for file in ${FILES[@]}; do
```

expands to

```
for file in 2011-09-04 21.43.02.jpg 2011-09-05 10.23.14.jpg 2011-09-09 12.31.16.jpg 2011-09-11 08.43.12.jpg ; do
```

But if you quote the expansion, bash adds double quotes around each term, so that:

```
for file in "${FILES[@]}"; do
```

expands to

```
for file in "2011-09-04 21.43.02.jpg" "2011-09-05 10.23.14.jpg" "2011-09-09 12.31.16.jpg" "2011-09-11 08.43.12.jpg" ; do
```

The simple rule of thumb is to always use `[@]` instead of `[*]` and quote array expansions if you want spaces preserved.

To elaborate on this a little further, the man page in the other answer is explaining that if unquoted, `$*` an `$@` behave the same way, but they are different when quoted. So, given

```
array=(a b c)
```

Then `$*` and `$@` both expand to

```
a b c
```

and `"$*"` expands to

```
"a b c"
```

and `"$@"` expands to

```
"a" "b" "c"
```

Answer (score 9):

If you had your array like this:
    #!/bin/bash

```
Unix[0]='Debian'
Unix[1]="Red Hat"
Unix[2]='Ubuntu'
Unix[3]='Suse'

for i in $(echo ${Unix[@]});
    do echo $i;
done
```

You would get:

```
Debian
Red
Hat
Ubuntu
Suse
```

I don't know why but the loop breaks down the spaces and puts them as an individual item, even you surround it with quotes.

To get around this, instead of calling the elements in the array, you call the indexes, which takes the full string thats wrapped in quotes.
It must be wrapped in quotes!

```
#!/bin/bash

Unix[0]='Debian'
Unix[1]='Red Hat'
Unix[2]='Ubuntu'
Unix[3]='Suse'

for i in $(echo ${!Unix[@]});
    do echo ${Unix[$i]};
done
```

Then you'll get:

```
Debian
Red Hat
Ubuntu
Suse
```

Answer (score 5):

For those who prefer set array in oneline mode, instead of using for loop

Changing `IFS` temporarily to new line could save you from escaping.

```
OLD_IFS="$IFS"
IFS=$'\n'

array=( $(ls *.jpg) )  #save the hassle to construct filename

IFS="$OLD_IFS"
```

Answer (score 3):

Not exactly an answer to the quoting/escaping problem of the original question but probably something that would actually have been more useful for the op:

```
unset FILES
for f in 2011-*.jpg; do FILES+=("$f"); done
echo "${FILES[@]}"
```

Where of course the expression would have to be adopted to the specific requirement (e.g. `*.jpg` for all or `2001-09-11*.jpg` for only the pictures of a certain day).

Answer (score 3):

```
#! /bin/bash

renditions=(
"640x360    80k     60k"
"1280x720   320k    128k"
"1280x720   320k    128k"
)

for z in "${renditions[@]}"; do
    echo "$z"
    
done
```

OUTPUT

> 640x360    80k     60k

> 1280x720   320k    128k

> 1280x720   320k    128k

`

Comment: Is this answer different/better from the ones already given?

Comment: yes, as you can see the output, each element inside renditions array is a string with spaces, and we loop it through without quotes around ${renditions[@]} then space will be treated as element delimiter, so here I am wrapping double quotes around ${renditions[@]}, which gives me the above output.

Answer (score 2):

Escaping works.

```
#!/bin/bash

FILES=(2011-09-04\ 21.43.02.jpg
2011-09-05\ 10.23.14.jpg
2011-09-09\ 12.31.16.jpg
2011-09-11\ 08.43.12.jpg)

echo ${FILES[0]}
echo ${FILES[1]}
echo ${FILES[2]}
echo ${FILES[3]}
```

Output:

```
$ ./test.sh
2011-09-04 21.43.02.jpg
2011-09-05 10.23.14.jpg
2011-09-09 12.31.16.jpg
2011-09-11 08.43.12.jpg
```

Quoting the strings also produces the same output.

Answer (score 1):

If the elements of `FILES` come from another file whose file names are line-separated like this:

```
2011-09-04 21.43.02.jpg
2011-09-05 10.23.14.jpg
2011-09-09 12.31.16.jpg
2011-09-11 08.43.12.jpg
```

then try this so that the whitespaces in the file names aren't regarded as delimiters:

```bash
while read -r line; do
    FILES+=("$line")
done < ./files.txt
```

If they come from another command, you need to rewrite the last line like this:

```bash
while read -r line; do
    FILES+=("$line")
done < <(./output-files.sh)
```

Answer (score 0):

Another solution is using a "while" loop instead a "for" loop:

```
index=0
while [ ${index} -lt ${#Array[@]} ]
  do
     echo ${Array[${index}]}
     index=$(( $index + 1 ))
  done
```

Answer (score 0):

If you aren't stuck on using `bash`, different handling of spaces in file names is one of the benefits of the [fish shell](https://fishshell.com). Consider a directory which contains two files: "a b.txt" and "b c.txt". Here's a reasonable guess at processing a list of files generated from another command with `bash`, but it fails due to spaces in file names you experienced:

```
# bash
$ for f in $(ls *.txt); { echo $f; }
a
b.txt
b
c.txt
```

With `fish`, the syntax is nearly identical, but the result is what you'd expect:

```
# fish
for f in (ls *.txt); echo $f; end
a b.txt
b c.txt
```

It works differently because fish splits the output of commands on newlines, not spaces.

If you have a case where you do want to split on spaces instead of newlines, `fish` has a very readable syntax for that:

```
for f in (ls *.txt | string split " "); echo $f; end
```

Answer (score -1):

I used to reset the [IFS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internal_field_separator) value and rollback when done.

```
# backup IFS value
O_IFS=$IFS

# reset IFS value
IFS=""

FILES=(
"2011-09-04 21.43.02.jpg"
"2011-09-05 10.23.14.jpg"
"2011-09-09 12.31.16.jpg"
"2011-09-11 08.43.12.jpg"
)

for file in ${FILES[@]}; do
    echo ${file}
done

# rollback IFS value
IFS=${O_IFS}
```

Possible output from the loop:

> 2011-09-04 21.43.02.jpg
>
> 2011-09-05 10.23.14.jpg
>
> 2011-09-09 12.31.16.jpg
>
> 2011-09-11 08.43.12.jpg