# find a option in string split by space in bash

Tags: bash, split, substring

I have a string like this, name it Options:

```
"printer-is-accepting-jobs=true printer-is-shared=false printer-location=Library printer-make-and-model='HP LaserJet 600 M601 M602 M603' printer-state=3"
```

they are "options=values" format, separated by spaces. but the "printer-make-and-model" has value with spaces.

tried command:

```
for word in $Options; do echo $word; done
```

all the HP LaserJet 600 M601 M602 M603 are splited.

How to deal with this in bash command?

Comment: perhaps one of the answers here will solve your problem http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9084257/bash-array-with-spaces-in-elements

Comment: Exactly, what do you want?

Comment: @h3nr1x. I would like to split the string to arrays, option=value for each line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `grep -oP`:

```
grep -oP "printer-make-and-model='\K[^']*" <<< "$s"
HP LaserJet 600 M601 M602 M603
```

OR using sed:

```
sed "s/^.*printer-make-and-model='\([^']*\).*/\1/" <<< "$s"
HP LaserJet 600 M601 M602 M603
```

Comment: Thank you! sorry, forget to mention, I'm on Mac. it doesn't have the -P options, what is the -P for?

Comment: I am also on OSX and `grep -P` is available (-P for PCRE)

Comment: :) @jaypal you can take any regex/code from my answer. There is no copyright as I learnt most of it from SO and other forums.

Answer (score 1):

[Anubhava's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22086288/970195) regex is good, so if you don't have `grep -P` option then you can try:

`ack` command:

```
$ ack -ho "printer-make-and-model='\K[^']*" <<< "$options"
HP LaserJet 600 M601 M602 M603
```

or `Perl`:

```
$ perl -nle "print $+{f} if /printer-make-and-model='(?'f'\K[^']*)/" <<< "$options"
HP LaserJet 600 M601 M602 M603
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with multiple awk statements:

```
while read record; do
    while read key value; do
        echo "K=($key) V=($value)"
    done< <(awk -F"=" '{printf("%s %s\n", $1, $2)}' <<< $record)
done< <(awk -F"printer-" '{for(i=2;i<NF;i++){printf("printer-%s\n", $i)}}' <<< $string)
```

This will split to output into key value pairs.

Comment: @"Tim Verhoeven", amazing! yours' give me the whole list! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Since you need to parse options, you can use `getopt`. However, this requires to use the evil `eval` command. So be careful about your input.

```
$ string="printer-is-accepting-jobs=true printer-is-shared=false printer-location=Library printer-make-and-model='HP LaserJet 600 M601 M602 M603' printer-state=3"
$ eval a=("$string")
$ eval b=($(getopt --long printer-make-and-model: -- ${a[@]/#/--} 2>/dev/null))
$ echo "${b[1]}"
HP LaserJet 600 M601 M602 M603
```

Comment: on my Mac, **echo "${b[1]}"** gets **"printer-make-and-model:"**

Comment: Frankly, I haven't tried it on mac, but I think, `getopt` on `mac` gives different output than on my system. try `for x in "${b[@]}; do echo $x; done` to see if the order of parameters has changed in the getopt output...