# Cut / echo inside bash

Tags: bash, echo, cut

Im confused with how the following cut works in the bash script.

Sample of `file.csv`:

```
#10.10.10.10;28;9.10.10.10: up;Something ;More random spaces
```

My script:

```
#!/bin/bash

csv_file="file.csv"

locations=( $( cut -d';' -f5 $csv_file ) )

for ((i=0; i < ${#locations[@]}; i++))
do
   echo "${locations[$i]}"
done
```

The result of the script is:

```
More
random
spaces
```

When I just copy and paste the cut in my CLI without any echos or variables the cut works as I´d expect and prints:

```
More random spaces
```

I am sure it´s some bracket or quote problem, but I just can't figure it out.

Comment: Why are you saving it to an array if you want the whole string?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your [command substitution `$(...)`](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/expansion/cmdsubst) undergo's [word splitting](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/WordSplitting) and [pathname expansion](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/expansion/globs):

```
a="hello world"
arr=($(echo "$a")); # Bad example, as it could have been: arr=($a)

echo "${arr[0]}" # hello
echo "${arr[1]}" # world
```

You can prevent this by wrapping the command substitution in double quotes:

```
arr=( "$(...)" )
echo "${arr[0]}" # hello world
```

Same applies to [parameter expansions](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/pe), eg:

```
a="hello world"
printf "<%s>" $a   # <hello><world>
printf "<%s>" "$a" # <hello world>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to quote the subshell command in the locations array:

```
locations=( "$( cut -d';' -f5 $csv_file )" )
```

More on the matter "arrays with spaces" here: [BASH array with spaces in elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9084257/bash-array-with-spaces-in-elements)

Answer (score 0):

The following statement creates an array of three elements:

```
location=(More random spaces)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `cut` command gives the string `More random spaces`, and when you convert that to an array it has 3 fields.

You can change your script into

```
cut -d";" -f5 < ${csv_file}
```

When you want to do some more with each line of output, you have more control with

```
csv_file="file.csv"

while IFS=";" read -r f1 f2 f3 f4 f5 f6_and_higher; do
   # Ignore fields f1 f2 f3 and f4
   echo "${f5}"
done < ${csv_file}
```

or (better) you can avoid the while loop with

```
awk -F ";" '{print $5}' ${csv_file}
```