# shell bash array: values with whitespace put it together

Tags: arrays, bash, shell

I need to add values into an array, but some values are separated with a whitespace. 
Then would be so fo example: 
"hello world"

```
myarr[0]: "hello 
myarr[1]: world"
```

How can I put it all together? 
For example:

```
myarr[0]: "hello world"
myarr[1]: "ciao mondo"
myarr[2]: ...
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Bash array with spaces in elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9084257/bash-array-with-spaces-in-elements)

Answer (score 0):

Use quotes around your strings with spaces :

```
ar+=("hello world" "ciao mondo")

echo ${ar[0]}
hello world

echo ${ar[1]}
ciao mondo
```

If you use the array in a loop, use quotes around the array:

```
for x in "${ar[@]}"; do echo "$x"; done
hello world
ciao mondo
```